# How do I disable Gmail app when consolidating into 3rd part Email client?

Tags: email, gmail, 5.1-lollipop

I decided to go with Blue Mail (Type) as my Android Email client. My question is how do I (or maybe should I) disable the Gmail application when I am using a consolidated Email client? If Blue Mail is doing the work, I don't want Gmail also syncing mail ....or maybe I do...I am not sure how to proceed.

Many thanks to the community for advice

Comment: That's too obvious to even ask. You already said 'disable' in your question? Will you be sued for disabling Gmail app because you got an alternative one to use? And you can't even also uninstall? And with even the gmail app still installed, you could explicitly disable syncing for it.

Comment: @Rexford2..it's a matter of functionality. I am not clear if disabling the app will preclude Blue Mail from accessing Gmail.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply disable the gmail application, or turn off synchronization of your account in gmail. This will not prevent other applications from accessing your gmail account.